# Killing thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

Im creating a server client program where client sends certain information to the server and get according response from the server.
For continuously listening from multiple clients I have a thread in server which continuously listens client request. whenever a request is received I start another thread and send that socket to run and start listening for other clients request.

here is the code for continuously listening

```
while(true){
    //serverListener is a ServerSocket object
    clientSocket = serverListener.accept();//Waiting for any client request

    //New thread started when request is received from any client
    Thread thread =new Thread(new serverThread(clientSocket), "ClientThread");
    thread.start();
}
```

Now my problem is that how can i stop the server. I know one alternative of using a boo lean variable in while loop and then changing the value, but the problem is when where thread is in waiting to get any connection at that time changing value of the boolean variable will also not stop the server.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: 1 solution which i found is that using the timeout for server socket and then using a boolean variable which checks whether server is stopped or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServerSocket#setSoTimeout() may of your interest, that will abandon accept if a timeout was reached. Be aware of catch the SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: timeout can be one of the solution but I dont want to stop it from listening

Comment: You may put accept() into a loop. When timeout check if stopping was requested. if not, accept() again.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the `serverListener` (which I assume is actually a `ServerSocket` or something) is closed by another thread.  This will generate a `java.net.SocketException` in `accept()` which will terminate the loop and the thread.

```
final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
Thread.sleep(10000);
serverSocket.close();
```

Comment: I have tried this approach and IO exception is thrown still server is running.

Comment: @Meherzad What does "still server is running" mean?  The socket should not be bound to the port after it is closed.  You mean the thread is still running?  The program does not shutdown?

Comment: Try setting setDaemon(true).  Call it on the server accept thread before starting it.  The client-server threads will then be daemon threads as well. The server app should then exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
volatile boolean finishFlag = false;

while(true){

            clientSocket = serverListener.accept();//Waiting for any client request

            if ( finishFlag ) 
               break;

            //New thread started when request is received from any client
            Thread thread =new Thread(new serverThread(clientSocket), "ClientThread");
            thread.start();
}
```

**EDIT:**

for interrupting listener, you should stop this thread from outside, and then accept( ) will throws IOException

```
    try {  
      while (true) {   
        Socket connection = server.accept( );

        try {    
          // any work here    
          connection.close( );
       }
       catch (IOException ex) {
         // maybe the client broke the connection early.
       }

       finally {
       // Guarantee that sockets are closed when complete. 
       try {
          if (connection != null) connection.close( );
       }
       catch (IOException ex) {}
    }    
  }    
  catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
  }
```

Comment: it keeps on waiting at accept() till a client request is received when new client is received then only it will go to next line. I have tried this case and also mentioned this in the question.